# How to change shipping address format in order view at admin panel

Tags: magento-1.9

I try to change Shipping Address format in order view at admin panel.

this is original shipping Address format

```
LastName FirstName
company name
postcode country region, city
T: telephone
```

but i want to change shipping address format when country is Japan

```
LastName FirstName
postcode country region, city
```

but i don't know how to change.

i open and see  app\design\adminhtml\default\templates\sales\order\view\info.phtml file, i saw only one code as the following:

```
<fieldset>
            <address><?php echo $_order->getShippingAddress()->getFormated(true) ?></address>
        </fieldset>
```

anyone can help me?

Answer (score 2):

You could do it in System->Configuration->Customer Configuration->Address Template. Field "HTML". But it also works for Billing address.